# adding resolve() to vuex action breaks data loading in component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, es6-promise

I have the following action in my VueX store
Adding resolve() makes component unable to load store data

```js
    fetch_resources({ commit, rootState }) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const url = '/api/resource/';

            rootState.axios_api.get(url)
                .then((response) => {
                    commit('SET_RESOURCES', response.data);
                    resolve(response.data);  // Adding this line breaks my component 
                }).catch((error) => {
                    reject(setErrorServer(error));
                });
        });
    },
```

Data is loaded and mutated in the store but is not loaded whitin the component called by this action on mount.

How should I fix my then().catch() to make it work ?

```js
    mounted() {
        this.fetch_resources().then(() => {
        }).catch((error) => {
            showErrorModal(error);
        });
    },

``̀̀̀`
```

Comment: Have you considered to use async/await instead of explicitly deal with promises? Would make this code much simpler...

Comment: opted for async await, tks !

Answer (score 0):

Axios themself returns promise, so you dont need to wrap it:

```js
    fetch_resources({ commit, rootState }) {
       
            const url = '/api/resource/';

            // also you may make a closure to param variable
            let com = commit

            return rootState.axios_api.get(url)
                .then((response) => {
                    commit('SET_RESOURCES', response.data);
                    // com('SET_RESOURCES', response.data);
                    resolve(response.data);  // Adding this line breaks my component 
                }).catch((error) => {
                    reject(setErrorServer(error));
                });

    },
```